# Distance between two Offsets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is no built-in method for `Offset` like `Point.distanceTo(Point<T> other)`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```dart
(offsetA - offsetB).distance
```

Offsets can be thought of as points or **vectors**. Arithmetic operators are overloaded for Offset to support vector operations.

[image]